# FluentNHibernate unidirectional many-to-many association

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a problem with ManyToMany mapping. This is what I have:

```
public class Asset
{
    public virtual int id {get;set;}
    //other props
    public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual string Slug { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping  unidirectional many-to-many

```
public class AssetMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Asset>
{

    public void Override(AutoMapping<Asset> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Tags)
        .Table("AssetTag")
        .ParentKeyColumn("AssetId")
        .ChildKeyColumn("TagId")
        .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

my first question is: Is the mapping right?

At the moment:

```
var asset = new Asset
    {
         //props
    };

asset.Tags.Add(new Tag{...});
repository.Save(asset)
```

It insert the tag but it does not insert any in the middle table "AssetTag"

with

```
var asset = new Asset
    {
         //props
    };

asset.Tags.Add(existing TAG);
repository.Save(asset)
```

it does insert the asset but it does not insert any in the middle table "AssetTag"

thanks for the help,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

The mapping is correct.

I'm using pretty much identical structure, same mapping, NHibernate 3.3.1.4000, SQL Server 2005 and it works fine. The only difference is I'm initializing the list in the master object's constructor. I'm also allowing NH to create the schema, incl. the relations table.